# Null uuid_t constant or function?

Tags: c++, posix

Is there a null `uuid_t` constant or a function that can return a null `uuid_t` in POSIX?

I have a function that should return a null `uuid_t` on failure, thus my need to generate/return a null `uuid_t`...

```
uuid_t getComponent(const string& name)
{
   if (components.find(name) == components.end())
       // return null uuid_t

   return components[name];
}
```

Comment: This is not C. Don't use wrong tags!

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_clear.3.html

Comment: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/uuid_is_null.3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try [uuid_clear()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/uuid_clear)?

---

Description:

> The uuid_clear function sets the value of the supplied uuid variable
>          uu to the NULL value.

---

[Example](https://gist.github.com/yoggy/4483031):

```
uuid_clear(uuid);
```